# get post content from WordPress site via xml-rpc in python

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

Dose any way to get post content from web site via xml-rpc by python :
for example i give the post id and get the post content of that post id

```
wp = Client("http://example.net/xmlrpc.php", 'xxxx', 'xxxxx')
wp.call(GetPosts())
wp.call(GetUserInfo())
post = WordPressPost()
wp.call("16941")
print(post.content)
```